# Lint warning for bad performance - 80+ Views

Tags: android, xml, performance, lint

I am getting this lint warning error:  `highscores.xml has more than 80 views bad for performance`.  This is my high scores table that has 15 rows and 3 columns.  This is the Lite version of my app and my paid version is going to hold 30 rows.

My question is how can I optimize this code?  There has to be a better way.

**highscores.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/scroll" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="65dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/clearHS"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scrollviewborder"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearlayout"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r1s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r1c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r1b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r2s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r2c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r2b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r3s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r3c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r3b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r4s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r4c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r4b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r5s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r5c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r5b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r6s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r6c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r6b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r7s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r7c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r7b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r8s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r8c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r8b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r9s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r9c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r9b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r10s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r10c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r10b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r11s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r11c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r11b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r12s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r12c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r12b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r13s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r13c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r13b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r14s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r14c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r14b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <View 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"       
                android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r15s"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/r15c"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="75"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/r15b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `ListView` instead of a `TableLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`. Not only will that allow you to only have as many rows as is really needed based upon available screen size, but you can get rid of the buttons, doing whatever it is the buttons are supposed to do based on clicking on list items.

Comment: I will look into ````ListView````.  The buttons for each row still needs to be on each row since they are unique to each row.  With that being said, ````ListView```` is still the route to go, correct?

Comment: @Matt: "The buttons for each row still needs to be on each row since they are unique to each row" -- IMHO, few apps with generally-considered good design look this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're pretty much into creating a `TableLayout` only, then you can add your `TableRow` programmatically instead of creating everything in your `layout.xml`(This will avoid `Lint` warnings & you can alter your table rows as per your wish). Here is a snippet on how you can do it.

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);

FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
table.setLayoutParams(lp);
table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        1.0f);
TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        1.0f);
for (int r = 0; r < 2; ++r)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    for (int c = 0; c < 2; ++c)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("A");
        row.addView(btn, cellLp);
    }
    table.addView(row, rowLp);
}
setContentView(table);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to refrain from this situation:

**1. Use RecyclerView**

If your design has many UI components that are similar to each other then you should use the `RecyclerView`, which is the best approach in this case and handle the recycling of views whenever needed.

**2. Use Compound Drawable**

If your UI has an image near `TextView` or `EditText` or `Button` then you can add an image to the left, right, top, bottom of `TextView` or `Button` or `EditText` using `drawable` property. You just need to use compound drawable no need to use a `LinearLayout` and `ImageView`.

If you want to add an image on the left side then, you can use drawable left like this:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
```

this will add an image to the left side of `TextView` or `Button` or `EditText` depends on which you are using this property.

**3. Use Constraint Layout**

This powerful layout really helps you to design your complex UI within this single layout, hence helps you to remove the nesting of the Layouts.